# click event working in Chrome but error in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, event-handling, onclick

I am writing a messaging system with jquery. When you click on a thread title with the class '.open_message', It opens a thread with all the messages for that thread via Ajax. My issue is that when the thread title is clicked it is not recognizing the id attribute for that specific thread title in firefox and IE. It works fine in chrome, though. Here is the code:

```
$('.open_message').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('unread');
        $(this).parent().addClass('read');
    $('.message_container').html('');
    var theID = e.currentTarget.attributes[0].value;
    theID = theID.replace('#', '');
    var url = '".$url."'; 
    var dataString = 'thread_id=' + theID; 
    $('.message_container').append('<img id=\"loading\" src=\"' + url + '/images/loading.gif\" width=\"30px\" />');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'get_thread.php',
            data: dataString,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('.message_container').append(result);
            }
        });
    return false;
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does your HTML look like?  It looks like you're assuming the ID is .attributes[0], but why is that a good assumption given that the order of attributes in .attributes is not defined by the spec?

Answer (score 0):

Within a click event, the element id is accessible using `this.id`. So the following should be a start...

```
$('.open_message').on('click', function(e) {
    var dataString = 'thread_id=' + this.id,
        url = '".$url."'; 
    $(this).parent().removeClass('unread').addClass('read');   // Combine for speed
    $('.message_container').html('').append( etc...

    etc...

});
```

I confess your `var url = '".$url."';` looks wonky to me, but I'll assume that bit is working OK ;)

You also may as well use `$.post` (as demonstrated [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)).